# Getting wrong bytes order when using struct on network byte order

Tags: c, network-programming

I am writing C code to read data from binary file written network byte order using GCC C compiler in Windows (codeblocks IDE) x64 intel PC.

The data bytes are following:

```
 00 16 54 43 41 54 20 20 00 AA 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 60 41 42 43 00 00 17
```

My code is:

```
#define SWAPPED(num) ((num>>8) | (num<<8))

struct  trd_t {
    unsigned short   length;     // First 2 bytes in the input data
    char    type;                // next 1 byte
    char    symbol[5];           // next 5 bytes
    unsigned short   trd_size;   // next 2 bytes
    uint64_t    trd_price;       // next 8 bytes
}; __attribute((packed))__;  // <--- EDIT: I tried this packed, but does not give right values either.

main ()
{
     struct trd_t *trd;
     unsigned char *buffer;
     unsigned short len;
     unsigned char type;
     ...
     buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(pkt_len);
     fread(buffer, pkt_len, 1 , fp)
     trd = (struct trd_t *) buffer;
     len = SWAPPED(trd->length);
     if (trd->type == 'T') {
       ....
     }
     ...
```

After casting (struct trd_t *)buffer, all the first few struct elements were capturing the correct data, such as length, type, symbol, and trd_size.
However, trd_price was wrong.
I expected it to capture "00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 60"
However, it captures "B8 60 41 42 43 00 00 17"

I tried using "**attribute((packed))**;" on the struct, but it did not help either.

Any idea?

Comment: I'd recommend to use the functions from the `htonx()` / `ntohx()` family to convert to network/host byte order.

Comment: Display pointer offset in bytes of `((char *)trd->trd_size-(char *)trd)` vs `((char *)trd->trd_price-(char *)trd)` to verify it's getting compiled as expected (+8, +10) for a start? (or even easier, check it in debugger) Also you didn't include code manipulating with `trd_price`, etc... I think few more lines of code wouldn't hurt, and it would make easier to see what you are doing.

Comment: Just a style note (and only my personal preference): as you already use `uint64_t`, I would get rid of the usigned shorts/chars too, I prefer the `uint16_t, uint8_t` way, as it's short and contains full info about the type.

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols.

Comment: @Ped7g I got +8 and +10

Comment: So the struct is compiled OK. Your problem is elsewhere. Once again, why don't you check in debugger, where the values come from, and how the memory at `*trd` really looks after `fread`. (actually right after line `trd = (struct trd_t *) buffer;` you can check `buffer` easily to see byte-level content, and then `*trd` should contain all values in wrong endianness (so `length` should be 0x1600`, etc).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  thanks for the tip. But, I can only do fread() once for reading the entire packet length then process it. Not allowed to use excessive fread().  I imagine that htonx() needs to fread() each data member before feeding it to htonx().

Comment: @electro _"I imagine that htonx() needs to fread() each data member before feeding it to htonx()"_ Not necessarily, why? You can apply it on your struct members instead of your `SWAP()` macro.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Got it.  However, the problem is uint64_t    trd_price is picking up wrong data due to padding on trd_size. (see immibis answer below)

Answer (score 0):

If you find a `struct` layout that completely matches some binary data you might happen to find somewhere, that's more or less pure luck (and might break with the next revision of your compiler).

C doesn't make any guarantee on struct member alignment or padding, although `packed` *may* help.

You should be reading the file content piecemeal into a byte buffer of appropriate size and extract your `struct` members from there.

Answer (score 0):

With the default layout there will be 6 bytes of padding after `trd_size`. So you thought you were getting this:

```
XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 60
^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lngth tp symbol         size  price
```

but you actually got this:

```
XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 60 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lngth tp symbol         size  padding           price
```

`__attribute__((packed))` is one correct solution for this problem, assuming that you don't mind your code being non-portable. If it doesn't work for you, you might be using it incorrectly (such as applying it to the variable instead of the struct) - it is not possible to tell without more information.

Comment: Correct.  That is exactly the issue. Extra paddings.
I tried using __attribute__((packed)) and it also does not solve it:
    struct  trd_t {
        unsigned short   length;
        char    type;
        char    symbol[5];
        unsigned short   trd_size;
        uint64_t    trd_price;
        //unsigned char    trd_price[8];
    }__attribute((packed))__;

By the way, if I use unsigned char trd_price[8], it works, but I will need to do conversion to little endian with byte shifts.